# Access my gmail from my android application

Tags: android, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to receive email from gmail android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146706/how-to-receive-email-from-gmail-android)

Is there a way to get all the received messages from my gmail to my android application.
Basically, I would like to get the received messages from Gmail account and if I receive a message from a particular sender I will perform some operations with the content of the message.
Is it possible to do so?? if yes, can you please tell me from where to start??

Comment: Try this one, it may help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146706/how-to-receive-email-from-gmail-android

Comment: I tried that one, but it was mainly for sending emails not receiving.

Answer (score 2):

[Javamail-android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list)

[this tutorial is very useful](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

to read unread messages you can use [gmail4j](https://github.com/spajus/gmail4j)

```
GmailClient client = new RssGmailClient();
GmailConnection connection = new HttpGmailConnection(LoginDialog.getInstance().show("Enter Gmail Login"));
client.setConnection(connection);
final List<GmailMessage> messages = client.getUnreadMessages();
for (GmailMessage message : messages) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Comment: It is for sending emails.
How can I play with it to make it for receiving emails??